# More than a riddle

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I was, for the most part, created to accompany something else.  It would *seem* like I'm just playing second fiddle to a jive-talking glory hog, but that's not actually the case; we both wound up being really famous and respected.  In fact, I'm arguably more famous than my master, because I get around more--I'm more versatile and less likely to get in the way of people, and I don't need as much gas to get to the same place.

But now it's all right, it's okay; we'll live to see another day.  As of fairly recently (well after Stack Overflow was founded), both myself and my master are currently being preserved by a very powerful organization for all of time.  We'll both be stayin' alive for a very long time, which is more than can be said of the three men to whom I most owe my existence.  It's a shame that two of them are dead, as we really had a great thing going on; if I can't have them, I don't want nobody else.  The oldest guy is still around, at least, but it just doesn't feel the same without his brothers, too.

Apparently, the three guys who made me originally worked with three others for a little while, though this was before my time.  They also had a younger brother who did his own separate thing, but I never met him (and he's dead too, apparently).

Also, who's taller, my master or me?  Well, that's actually an interesting question.  It depends on whether or not he's allowed to show you his penis.  Yes, really.  Though I suppose it doesn't really matter anyway, because we're both about the same height regardless.

Finally, not that it matters much to me, but everyone generally likes to pretend my master's little brother doesn't exist.

## Hints

> It's a very specific thing.  A famous thing.

---

> It's older than I am, but I don't know if it's older than you (StackExchange attracts a pretty wide audience these days).

---

> If you tried to sell one of these without getting permission from a *different* large organization, they would get very mad and might sue you.

Comment: the answers of your last puzzle fits well

Comment: I promise, this is not related to that one.  Or is it?

Comment: Are you sure "lateral-thinking" is the right tag for this riddle? Based on the hints it suggest "knowledge" or "trivia".

Comment: @theGhapla You're probably right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> The song *Stayin Alive* by the Bee Gees

I was, for the most part, created to accompany something else.

> It was the theme for *Saturday Night Fever*.

It would seem like I'm just playing second fiddle to a jive-talking glory hog, but that's not actually the case; we both wound up being really famous and respected. In fact, I'm arguably more famous than my master, because I get around more--I'm more versatile and less likely to get in the way of people, and I don't need as much gas to get to the same place.

> The "master" would be *Saturday Night Fever*, the movie for which it was made. The movie was a critical success, and the song was a huge hit. The movie made John Travolta a household name, and catapulted the Bee Gees to the top of the charts. The song still gets airplay.

But now it's all right, it's okay; we'll live to see another day. As of fairly recently (well after Stack Overflow was founded), both myself and my master are currently being preserved by a very powerful organization for all of time. We'll both be stayin' alive for a very long time,

> The movie (and by extension the song as well) was recently added to the Library of Congress' National Film Registry.

which is more than can be said of the three men to whom I most owe my existence. It's a shame that two of them are dead, as we really had a great thing going on; if I can't have them, I don't want nobody else. The oldest guy is still around, at least, but it just doesn't feel the same without his brothers, too.

> The Bee Gees. They were a group of three Gibb brothers, the younger two of which have since passed. Only Barry Gibb, the oldest, survives.

Apparently, the three guys who made me originally worked with three others for a little while, though this was before my time.

> The band has had 3 other people as members, but by the time of the movie, it was only the brothers Gibb.

They also had a younger brother who did his own separate thing, but I never met him (and he's dead too, apparently).

> Andy Gibb was the youngest of the brothers, but was never part of the band, instead becoming a solo artist.

Also, who's taller, my master or me? Well, that's actually an interesting question. It depends on whether or not he's allowed to show you his penis. Yes, really. Though I suppose it doesn't really matter anyway, because we're both about the same height regardless.

> Not entirely sure here. I imagine we're talking in terms of popularity, or in sales? Not sure. I am sure that this is referring to the movies R-rated theatrical version versus its PG-rated cut that was made to accomodate the younger crowd that made the song such a hit.

Finally, not that it matters much to me, but everyone generally likes to pretend my master's little brother doesn't exist.

> The movie had a sequel, also called *Stayin Alive*, is widely considered to be a terrible movie, even winning some Razzies as a result.

Comment: Technically, I was referring to <base64>dGhlIHNvdW5kdHJhY2sgYXMgYSB3aG9sZQ==</base64>, but I'll grant credit because you hit all the salient points.  Also, <base64>InRhbGxlciIgbWVhbnMgImxvbmdlciBydW5uaW5nIHRpbWUi</base64>.  Otherwise, good job!

Comment: this answer isn't really complete until it points out certain phrases in the question that appear ... well, you know where they appear. Right?

Answer (score 2):

You are

> A Beetle

"In fact, I'm arguably more famous than my master, because I get around more--I'm more versatile and less likely to get in the way of people, and I don't need as much gas to get to the same place."

> I think the VW Beetle could be seen as more well known than Volkswagen, and Volkswagen has a recent bad rep for their recent emissions scandal.

"Both myself and my master are currently being preserved by a very powerful organization for all of time."

> This might be a reference to the Beatles and preservation of their music?  Or a reference to the John Lennon Museum?

"It's a shame that two of them are dead, as we really had a great thing going on; if I can't have them, I don't want nobody else. The oldest guy is still around, at least, but it just doesn't feel the same without his brothers, too."

> Of the Beatles, John Lennon and George Harrison are dead, Paul McCartney and Ringo Starr are still alive.

"Apparently, the three guys who made me originally worked with three others for a little while, though this was before my time. They also had a younger brother who did his own separate thing, but I never met him (and he's dead too, apparently)."

> I'm not sure how to actually match this clue, the history of the formation of the Beatles doesn't seem to match well but I might be missing something.  Also not sure who the younger brother is.  Maybe this is a reference to Volkswagen, I'll have to do some research.

"Also, who's taller, my master or me? Well, that's actually an interesting question. It depends on whether or not he's allowed to show you his penis. Yes, really. Though I suppose it doesn't really matter anyway, because we're both about the same height regardless.

Finally, not that it matters much to me, but everyone generally likes to pretend my master's little brother doesn't exist."

> Also not sure if this matches well, but it could be talking about the emissions scandal and measuring emissions values?  And the "master's little brother" could be one of the companies that Volkswagen owns, but most of them are well known (Audi, Porsche, Bugatti, Lamborghini) so I'm not sure.

I'll probably update this answer soon as I do more research...

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Pants or underwear

Because well:

"I was, for the most part, created to accompany something else. It would seem like I'm just playing second fiddle to a jive-talking glory hog, but that's not actually the case; we both wound up being really famous and respected. In fact, I'm arguably more famous than my master, because I get around more."

> Pants & underwear are meant to be worn arround your low-back and "playing second fiddle to a jive-talking glory hog" seems like an allusion to a penis.
>
>  The next line may refer to well-known companies that make jeans and/or underwear.

"But none of that matters any more, because both myself and my master are currently being watched after by very powerful people."

> A reference to said companies.

"We'll both stay alive for a very long time, which is more than can be said of (two out of three of) the men to whom I most owe my existence."

> Styles of underwear & jeans don't vary too much over the years. There is some variation but not much. Today's jeans are quite similar to those from even the 60s. In that case, many in the industry are no longer living. Most likely, only 1 of the 3 that make today's models are from back then. Even the jeans themselves can be inherited, if well preserved.

"Also, who's taller, my master or me? Well, that's actually an interesting question. It depends on whether or not he's allowed to show you his penis. Yes, really. Though I suppose it doesn't really matter anyway, because we're both about the same height regardless."

> When the penis is brought outside the pants, for example when urinating, the "master" of the pants is bigger than the pants (or underwear) itself, because he is breaking outside of the manner in which they are to be worn. "Though I suppose it doesn't really matter anyway, because we're both about the same height regardless" - the pants & underwear surround the body parts of their "master".

"Finally, not that it matters much to me, but everyone generally likes to pretend my master's little brother doesn't exist."

> Because pants (and underwear) are meant to hide one's genitals.

Comment: Please spoiler tag your answers by putting >! in front of each line that is to be hidden.

Comment: A coffin/Tomb ?

Comment: No, it is not a coffin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who the "master" is you keep referring to:

> Elvis?

But I'm pretty sure the answer is

> Disco

The three you refer to who played a big part where two of them are dead are:

> The Bee Gees of which some of their lyrics and songs are in the riddle.

The large organisation preserving them for all time I'd say

> I-Tunes

Comment: You're partially right, but keep going!

Comment: Which one is wrong?

Comment: I'll just say that the answer's a bit more specific than that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> Subconscious

If so it's 3am. I'll add explanation after I get a few hours of shuteye.

Comment: Nope.  Keep trying.